# Change entity framework database first auto generated domain classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

Can i change entity framework database first auto generated classes (under .tt) to derive from a base class (BaseEntity)?

Some of my domain classes has two property (CreateDateTime & CreateUserId) and i want to set this properties automatically before SaveChanges() with the following code:

```
private void AuditFields()
{
    foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>().Where(x => x.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added))
    {
        entry.CreateDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        entry.CreateUserId = CurrentUser.Id;
    }
}
```

in top of those partial classes i saw the following warning:

> Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you planning then to go code first?
Will you need to regenerate ever again ?

If you know the answer to those questions. Or have at least considered the impact.
See [Reverse engineer code first to existing DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj200620.aspx)

This gets you a model you can start with

OtherWise:
The partial class approach may help. Last time i tried (EF4) the generated code was partial.
You leave the generated class alone and add a partial section

```
public partial class MyGeneratedClass : SexyBaseObject 
{
//...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i cant use code first approach in project i 'm working on.

Comment: As far as I remember, EF's generated classes are usually created as partial classes so that you can add on metadata and other things, so something like this should work whether you're using code first or not.